# unselect checkmarks into Collectionview in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, uicollectionview

I am showing collocation view with multiple checkmarks in main view controller.its working fine

[image]

after select checkmarks data showing into next view controller.
it is also working. when i back to main view controller which I selected check marks are not unchecked. how to uncheck selected checkmarks.

I used this reference 
https://github.com/maximbilan/CheckMarkView

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkMarkViews: CheckMarkView!


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        cell.CoutnryImages.downloadImageFrom(link: imagesarray[row] , contentMode: .scaleToFill)

        cell.countrynmae.text = itemsarray[row]

        cell.checkMarkViews.setNeedsDisplay()

      return cell

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = CollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        var indexpathvalues = indexPath.row   

        cell.checkMarkViews.checked = !cell.checkMarkViews.checked

        if cell.checkMarkViews.checked == true
        {

           PassedID.append(idarray[indexpathvalues])
            _selectedcell.add(indexpathvalues)

        }
        else
        {
        if PassedID.isEmpty
            {
                print("no Item found ")
            }
            else
            {
                 _selectedcell.remove(indexpathvalues)
                PassedID.removeLast()
            }

        }

    }

    @IBAction func Addbutton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

              performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender: self)

    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let vc = segue.destination as? nextViewController

        vc?.arrayvalues = self.PassedID

        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)       

    }

how to uncheck the multiple selection after back to main view controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // get visible cells and un check them

    let visibleCell = cc.visibleCells as! [CustomCollectionViewCell]

    for cell in visibleCell
    {
        // un check here

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronize your cells with actual selection state, you need to store it. Ideally, you will need `model` here, which will contain state (like `isSelected` or something). But in the listed code would be just enough store `Set` (or `Array`, doesn't actually matter) of selected cells' `[IndexPath]`.

Once a user selects/deselects some cell you should update your collection (append/remove appropriate `IndexPath`).

In `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` method you should update your checkmarks' state.